# ExtAudioFileRead gives different result in iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to extract Linear PCM data from a MP3 file.
Before iOS 5, I could do it successfully using *AudioToolbox* framework, specifically *ExtAudioFileRead* function.
However, **in iOS 5 the *ExtAudioFileRead* function gives completely different result from that in iOS 4.**

**First, it cannot read all the packets in the source MP3 file.**
For example, it reads only 1637 packets while the source MP3 file has 2212 packets in total.

**Second, the PCM values obtained from the function are completely different from those obtained  in iOS 4.**

I can't figure out what I did wrong :(
The same framework, the same function, and the same code... but completely different results?
I doubt it is a bug of iOS 5 so I reported the problem to Apple already.
But Apple has not answer to my bug reporting for 2 weeks!

Here's the code that causes the problem.
After executing the code, I expect to have the correct PCM data in *pcmBuffer*.
In iOS 4, the code gives the result what I expected to.
But in iOS 5, the result is completely different and wrong.

Please, somebody help me!

```
OSStatus status;
ExtAudioFileRef fileRef;

CFURLRef fileURL = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
status = ExtAudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, &fileRef);  

AudioStreamBasicDescription dataFormat; 
dataFormat.mSampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE;
dataFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
dataFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
dataFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
dataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
dataFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
dataFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2;
dataFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2;

UInt32 propDataSize;

AudioStreamBasicDescription originalDataFormat;
propDataSize = (UInt32)sizeof(originalDataFormat);
status = ExtAudioFileGetProperty(fileRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileDataFormat, &propDataSize, &originalDataFormat);

SInt64 numPackets;
propDataSize = sizeof(numPackets);
status = ExtAudioFileGetProperty(fileRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileLengthFrames, &propDataSize, &numPackets);

propDataSize = (UInt32)sizeof(dataFormat);
status = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(fileRef, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, propDataSize, &dataFormat);

numPackets = (SInt64)numPackets / (SInt64)(originalDataFormat.mSampleRate / SAMPLE_RATE);

size_t bufferSize = (size_t)(numPackets * sizeof(SInt16));
SInt16 *pcmBuffer = (SInt16 *)malloc(bufferSize);

AudioBufferList bufList;
bufList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
bufList.mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = 1; 
bufList.mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = bufferSize;
bufList.mBuffers[0].mData = pcmBuffer;

ExtAudioFileSeek(fileRef, 0);
UInt32 totalFramesRead = 0;
do {
    UInt32 framesRead = numPackets - totalFramesRead;
    bufList.mBuffers[0].mData = pcmBuffer + (totalFramesRead * (sizeof(SInt16)));
    ExtAudioFileRead(fileRef, &framesRead, &bufList);
    totalFramesRead += framesRead;
    if(framesRead == 0) {
        break;
    }
    NSLog(@"read %lu frames\n", framesRead);
} while (totalFramesRead < numPackets);

int totalPackets = totalFramesRead;
status = ExtAudioFileDispose(fileRef);

NSLog(@"numPackets : %lld, totalPackets : %d", numPackets, totalPackets);
```

Comment: This code worked fine for me on iOs 6.1, when I made modifications to allow stereo input. That is, I changed the number of channels and the number of Bytes per packet for two-channel, 16-bit audio.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch. I noted that the number is different if the original sampling rate of the song is different. Back to square 1.